# How to access a value in an object when the object is filtered by another value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects that I need to filter by a value nested in each object.
Here's what the object looks like :

```json
[
  {
    "location_area": {
      "name": "kanto-route-2-south-towards-viridian-city",
      "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/296/"
    },
    "version_details": [
      {
        "max_chance": 10,
        "encounter_details": [
          {
            "min_level": 7,
            "max_level": 7,
            "condition_values": [
              {
                "name": "time-morning",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/3/"
              }
            ],
            "chance": 5,
            "method": {
              "name": "walk",
              "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/"
            }
          }
        ],
        "version": {
          "name": "heartgold",
          "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/15/"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I filter according to the value returned by version_details.version.name.
Here's my filter :

```js
location
  .map((l) => l.version_details.filter((lv) => lv.version.name === game))
```

The problem is that when it is filtered, I can only access version_details (which is normal) but I need to access location_area.name for the objects returned after the filtering.
How can I filter my array of objects to correspond to the value in version.name and then access location_area.name for the objects returned ?

Comment: Instead of filter directly using `filter()`, you can use `map()` to set an `isVisible` property (boolean) and only display thoses with `isVisible === true`, keeping all your data and an access to `location_area.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **think** you're saying you want to get a mapped version of `location` that has objects where the `version_details` have been filtered so they only include ones whose `.version.name` property matches the variable `name` (I renamed it from `game` in the question).

If so, you can do that like this:

```
const filtered = location.map((l) => {
    const version_details = l.version_details.filter((lv) => lv.version.name === name);
    return {
        ...l,
        version_details,
    };
});
```

That creates a new object for every element in `location` that has all the properties of the original object, but with a filtered `version_details`.

Live example (I renamed `location` to `loc` because top-level code in browsers can't redeclare the `location` variable):

```js
const loc = [
    {
        location_area: {
            name: "kanto-route-2-south-towards-viridian-city",
            url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/296/",
        },
        version_details: [
            {
                max_chance: 10,
                encounter_details: [
                    {
                        min_level: 7,
                        max_level: 7,
                        condition_values: [
                            {
                                name: "time-morning",
                                url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/3/",
                            },
                        ],
                        chance: 5,
                        method: {
                            name: "walk",
                            url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/",
                        },
                    },
                ],
                version: {
                    name: "heartgold",
                    url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/15/",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
];

const name = "heartgold";
const filtered = loc.map((l) => {
    const version_details = l.version_details.filter((lv) => lv.version.name === name);
    return {
        ...l,
        version_details,
    };
});
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or somewhat more concisely:

```
const filtered = location.map((l) => ({
    ...l,
    version_details: l.version_details.filter((lv) => lv.version.name === game),
}));
```

Comment: Thx it was nearly that but I used your solution and did another filter and it works :)